# How to autosize form fields

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs4

I use form.fields from EXTJS API. My application is totally dynamically.

It is possible to autosize combobox thanks to value which are on store ?
Or i need to make my own method... ?!

Actually, my combobox , is declared as following :

```
itemId : 'materialid',

         xtype : 'combobox',
            anchor : '35%',
            store : materialstore,
            id : 'Material',
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'data',
            width : 50,
            valueField: 'data',
            editable : false,
            grow : true,
            enforceMaxLength : true,
            listeners : {

                render : function(me){

                    var obj = materialstore.findRecord('data',materialdefaultvalue);
                    me.setValue(obj.get('data'),obj);


                }

            },

         padding : '0 30 0 30',
         fieldLabel : 'Material',

          name : 'material',
          listeners : {


            blur : function(me){


                var fieldvalue = me.getValue();
                var sel = monPretree.getView().getSelectedRecords();

                for ( var i = 0 ; i < sel.length ; i++){

                    alert(sel[i].get('id') + ' && ' + material);

                }
            }
          }
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. Your best bet would be either to set a fixed width (like you have) or set it to `'100%'`.

A quick note for future questions: it is better to ask them over on the [Sencha forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/), as you will get a quicker response.

Comment: On sencha forum, i haven't got answers ... maybe my english is too bad .. !
I don't want fixed width, because often value in combobox are just 2/3 characters or more 20...

Comment: Unfortunately nothing you can do then at this point. I'll add it as a feature request in our internal tracker (I work for Sencha).

Comment: Oh great ! 
I think , it is a nice posibilty :) !